# rabbitmq-server boot failed on mac os x el capitan

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, osx-elcapitan

This is my first time using rabbitmq.

I installed rabbitmq through homebrew by

```
brew update
brew install rabbitmq
```

then I insert the path in my `.bash_profile` with

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
```

I restart my terminal and type

```
rabbitmq-server
```

to start the server but the following error appeared

```
              RabbitMQ 3.6.6. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  ######  ##        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...


BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbitmq_mqtt,
       {{shutdown,
            {failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_mqtt_listener_sup_:::1883',
                {shutdown,
                    {failed_to_start_child,
                        {ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}},
                        {shutdown,
                            {failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,
                                {listen_error,
                                    {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883},
                                    eaddrinuse}}}}}}},
        {rabbit_mqtt,start,[normal,[]]}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbitmq_mqtt,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_mqtt_listener_sup_:::1883',{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,{ranch_listener_sup,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}},{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,ranch_acceptors_sup,{listen_error,{acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883},eaddrinuse}}}}}}},{rabbit_mqtt,start,[normal,[]]}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ()

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

I run `rabbitmqctl status` and below is the result

```
Status of node rabbit@localhost ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@localhost]

rabbit@localhost:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  other nodes on localhost: ['rabbitmq-cli-77']
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details: 
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-77@Ling-Air'
- home dir: /Users/Ling
- cookie hash: 0YMYFZ/TBrgNjOy7lBAw4A==
```

What should I do? I already restarted my computer and reinstalling rabbitmq but that did not solved the problem.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`eaddrinuse` is an Erlang error, You have the port `1883` used by another process

Comment: right, thank you. There is mosquitto server using the port. I solved the problem by stopping the mosquitto server and restarting the rabbitmq